# Run multiple block snippets in parallel with bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing

Say I have a series of commands like this in a bash script:

```bash
echo set1
mkdir /path/to/output/set_1/
python my_script1.py /path/to/output/set_1/

echo set2
mkdir /path/to/output/set_2/
python my_script2.py /path/to/output/set_2/

...
```

Let's say I want to run each *block* in parallel, i.e. I want to run all of the first 3 lines in sequence but parallel to the next 2 instructions.

How do I go about it?

Comment: `echo set1; (mkdir /path/to/output/set_1/; python my_script1.py /path/to/output/set_1/) &` ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that number of snippets is`n` you can write:

```
for 1 in {1..n}
do
   echo $i
   (mkdir /path/to/output/set_1/
    python my_script2.py /path/to/output/set_2/) &
done
```